# Dependency injection not working inside Grails service

Tags: grails, dependency-injection, spring-security

I have a class that I moved under the grails-app/services directory in order to inject the springSecurityService. This class is the implementation (Is that the proper terminology?) of the spring userDetailsService class. Here is my declaration in resources.groovy:

```
userDetailsService(com.company.product.PracticeUserDetailsService) {
    grailsApplication = ref('grailsApplication')
}
```

This class is extending `GormUserDetailsService.`

My attempted dependencyInjection results in a null object.

```
class PracticeUserDetailsService extends GormUserDetailsService{

    def springSecurityService

    UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username, boolean loadRoles) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        // impl omitted
    }
}
```

If I create some test controller or some service in grails and inject the `springSecurityService`, it works fine. So, there is perhaps something about this particular class that is not placing it in the Grails ecosystem. I checked out [this](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/spring.html#springdslAdditional) to try to manually inject it as follows:

```
beans = {
    springSecurityTEST(grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService) {}

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Move `PracticeUserDetailsService` from `grails-app/services` to `src/groovy` and change your Spring bean definition in `resources.groovy` to:

```
userDetailsService(com.company.product.PracticeUserDetailsService) {
    grailsApplication = ref('grailsApplication')
    springSecurityService = ref('springSecurityService')
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. I get that now; you are declaring springSecurityService as a referenced bean for the userDetailsService bean. But can you explain why it did not work placing that class under grails-app/services?

Comment: @jcd Spring beans are automatically created for services, so by putting the class in `grails-app/services` and defining a bean for it in `resources.groovy`, you're defining the same Spring bean twice, which can only lead to trouble

Answer (score 0):

For me it happened when I used `GrailsApp.run(Application, args)` to run the app...